# c# Excelpackage reading cell range into a datatable

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Using C# I can manage to read in range of cells using Excel interop. But it's having trouble keeping consistent with dollar values and percentages. So I'm trying out EEPLus.

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@excelFilePath);
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
var Summary = workbook1.Worksheets[1];
```

and then using the following

```
Convert.ToString(Summary.Cells["I35"].Value);
```

I get a decent value.

But what I would like to do is something the following

```
 Summary.Cells["E29:P32"].Value
```

and put that into a datatable. There is a method for ImportDataTable but it moves from datatable to excel. Does something similarly simple exist for excel to datatable?

Cheers.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/
http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in method, but you can try something like this:

```
var range = summary.Cells["E6:G7"];
DataTable tbl = GetDataTableFromRange(range);
```

and GetDataTableFromRange method:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromRange(ExcelRange range)
{
  DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
  tbl.Columns.Add("Column1");
  tbl.Columns.Add("Column2");
  tbl.Columns.Add("Column3");

  int dataTableColumn = 0;
  DataRow newRow = null;
  int currRow = -1;
  foreach (var item in range)
  {
    if (currRow != item.Start.Row)
    {
      newRow = tbl.NewRow();
      tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
      dataTableColumn = 0;
      currRow = item.Start.Row;
    }
    newRow[dataTableColumn] = item.Value.ToString();
    dataTableColumn++;
  }
  return tbl;
}
```

Comment: In my case I must add .Copy() after the method call:  
`DataTable tbl = GetDataTableFromRange(range).Copy();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public bool readXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";        //Here I am using "blind insert". You can specify the column names Blient inset is strongly not recommanded
        string eachVal = "";
        bool status;
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            queryString += "(";
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                eachVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim();
                queryString += "'" + eachVal + "',";
            }
            queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
            if (row % 1000 == 0)        //On every 1000 query will execute, as maximum of 1000 will be executed at a time. 
            {
                queryString += ")";
                status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
                if (status == false)
                    return status;
                queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";
            }
            else
            {
                queryString += "),";
            }
        }
        queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
        status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
        return status;
    }
}
```

Source: http://sforsuresh.in/read-data-excel-sheet-insert-database-table-c/

Answer (score 0):

***This worked for me to find the range and store the values of Excel file in Datatable :***

```
    public virtual DataTable ReadExcelFileToDatable(IFormFile file) //HttpPostedFileBase file
    {
        bool hasHeader = true;
        var tbl = new DataTable();
        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(file.OpenReadStream())) // file.InputStream 
        {
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
            if (ws != null)
            {
                foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                {
                    if (firstRowCell.Text != "" && firstRowCell.Text != null)
                        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                    else
                        break;
                }
                var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                    DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        if (cell.Text != "" && cell.Text != null)
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                }
                return tbl; 
            }
            else
            {
                return tbl;
            }
        }
    }
```